# How do I create my own domain?

Tags: domain

As of recently I've been wondering on how to make my own domain for server uses and whatnot, like how you can go on [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com), search for a domain you want to buy and get it, but how would GoDaddy make those domains? Is it possible to make a domain without doing so?

Comment: A 'domain' is merely an address you have the right to use. It is not a web site or a server. That is a completely separate issue & one that is not on-topic here. If you 'buy' a domain from godaddy or anyone, you are not actually buying it *from* them, merely *through* them. Domains as properties are governed by [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/)

Comment: Go Daddy has a rather dubious reputation. I would advise you to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

The Domain Name System is just an address book. Technically all that's needed to make a domain is to add a single record or two – for example, the domain `example.com` exists because of these records:

```
example.com.  NS  a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.  NS  b.iana-servers.net.
```

The rest is just business procedures (such as getting the information between organizations, actually getting paid, etc.). There are no tangible objects that need to be created, nor blocks that need to be mined, etc.

From the technical side, domains in the DNS system are *delegated*. The organization which controls the "root" (ICANN) delegates control of TLDs to various organizations acting as registries, and those registries – upon request by a registrar – will delegate individual domain names to customers such as you. (And you can further delegate subdomains to someone else.)

> how would GoDaddy make those domains

When you buy a domain at GoDaddy or another registrar, they send information to the TLD's *registry* requesting that the domain be delegated to some DNS nameservers. (For example, the central .com registry is VeriSign.) Usually this is sent using an automated protocol called EPP, but the registry might accept any method – even email used to be common.

When the registry receives the information, they create DNS "NS" records on the TLD pointing to whatever nameservers were provided by the registrar. (Usually the domain starts off with GoDaddy's free nameservers, but you can change them to custom ones.) The registry also manages the WHOIS/RDAP database and updates it with your contact information.

> Is it possible to make a domain without doing so

No, you always have to go through the registry *somehow*. If they don't add the NS records to their DNS zone, then the rest of the world simply won't know that your domain exists.

Of course, it is possible to establish your own company as a new registrar, and bypass GoDaddy &c. by talking to the TLD directly, but it will cost quite a bit – only worth doing so if you're dealing with hundreds of domains per day. (That's what large hosting providers do.)

Usually the registry has some official process for establishing a new registrar and obtaining EPP access; for example, see [VeriSign's "new registrar" requirements](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/channel-resources/become-a-registrar/index.xhtml).

Comment: Nice job, thanks for summing up my youtube and googling from the past, good memories!!

Answer (score 2):

To understand why this is not really something you can do you should learn how DNS works. Summarising in the extreme (to the point if being technically slightly incorrect even) -

Name servers are aware of "root name servers". These special name servers have records for the name servers of the top level domains (eg .com, .edu, .biz,. givt, .nz, .us, .xxx etc) . These top level domains are controlled by various government/pseudo government/private entities which dictate the terms of subdomains.

Registrars like Godaddy contract with these companies to buy domains and handle the registration and name server settings. THEY PAY THE APPROPIATE TLD OWNERS for this, and add a web Interface and structure to hook into multiple registries - very often with high API fees and low per domain fees.

You could possibly go to these registrars and set up your own agreements, but its very expensive and quite complex. so it does not make sense to do.

You can, of-course set up your own name servers with whatever domains you like without involving a registrar but these will only work for those people using your name servers.  There were alternative registries when the Internet was young, but they have fallen away.(Google " alternic" for a famous example)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create my own domain?

From a purely technical standpoint, you would use DNS software such as [BIND 9](https://www.isc.org/bind/), which is available for download [here](https://www.isc.org/download/) (click the link that says `BIND 9` to the right of `ISC DHCP` and `Kea`).

After installing the software, you could then create any domains you wanted and assign IPs to them. Any computer using that PC/server for DNS resolution would then have access to those domains.

*The basic drawback to this is that these domains would be limited to networks you controlled (i.e. not the public internet).*

> How would GoDaddy make those domains?

As detailed in other answers, GoDaddy doesn't. They are strictly a *registrar*, an entity who processes so-called "second-level" domains (e.g. `example.com`). [Note that there are also resellers, who contract with registrars to offer domains as well.]

Regarding who "makes" domains for the public internet, there are multiple entities involved. Broadly speaking, however, [Registry operators](https://icannwiki.org/Registry) work along with [ICANN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN) to maintain generic [top level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (gTLDs)<sup>1</sup>, some of which are offered to the public via registrars (ex. `.com`, `.net`, and `.org`).

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is in contrast to [country-code top level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) (ccTLDs), such as `.us` and `.uk`, which are delegated by [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) (an organization controlled by ICANN) to national registries which are managed locally.*

---

gTLDs are split into two main categories:

- [Sponsored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponsored_top-level_domain) - Those proposed by private agencies or organizations.
- [Unsponsored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsponsored_top-level_domain) - Those without an "owner", where ICANN has stronger influence.

*Unsponsored*

The original (unsponsored) domains created in the 1980s were `.com`, `.edu`, `.gov`, `.int`, `.mil`, `.net`, and `.org`. Later, in the early 2000s, `.biz`, `.info`, `.name`, and `.pro` were added as well.

*Sponsored*

"Sponsored" domains are domains proposed to ICANN by private agencies or organizations, as mentioned above. If the proposal is accepted, the organization proposing the domain becomes generally responsible for maintaining that domain (they become the registry operator).

In the past, the proposal process has been initiated at very specific times set by ICANN when they have felt there was a need to expand the total number of gTLDs available.

*Who Maintains What?*

If you want to see a big list of gTLDs and who manages them, you may want to take a look at this [official ICANN Registry list](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/listing-2012-02-25-en).

> Is it possible to make a domain without doing so?

For private networks, yes. For the public internet, probably not.